# Equivalence between tensor and matrix

Tags: matrix, tensors

I need have to create a real antisymmetric tensor whose elements are given as $p_{abcd}$
$${\displaystyle p_{abcd}={\begin{cases}
+p_{\sigma\left(abcd\right)} & {\text{if }}\sigma(a,b,c,d){\text{ is an even permutation }}\\
-p_{\sigma\left(abcd\right)} & {\text{if }}\sigma(a,b,c,d){\text{ is an odd permutation }}\\
\;\;\,0 & {\text{otherwise}.}
\end{cases}}}$$

For example if I need to create a random real antisymmetric tensor of order 4, then:first step,
$$p_{cd}=\begin{bmatrix}p_{11,cd} & p_{12,cd} & p_{13,cd} & p_{14,cd}\\
p_{21,cd} & p_{22,cd} & p_{23,cd} & p_{24,cd}\\
p_{31,cd} & p_{32,cd} & p_{33,cd} & p_{34,cd}\\
p_{41,cd} & p_{42,cd} & p_{43,cd} & p_{44,cd}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then
$$p=\begin{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p_{11,11} & p_{12,11} & p_{13,11} & p_{14,11}\\
p_{21,11} & p_{22,11} & p_{23,11} & p_{24,11}\\
p_{31,11} & p_{32,11} & p_{33,11} & p_{34,11}\\
p_{41,11} & p_{42,11} & p_{43,11} & p_{44,11}
\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}p_{11,12} & p_{12,12} & p_{13,12} & p_{14,12}\\
p_{21,12} & p_{22,12} & p_{23,12} & p_{24,12}\\
p_{31,12} & p_{32,12} & p_{33,12} & p_{34,12}\\
p_{41,12} & p_{42,12} & p_{43,12} & p_{44,12}
\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}p_{11,13} & p_{12,13} & p_{13,13} & p_{14,13}\\
p_{21,13} & p_{22,13} & p_{23,13} & p_{24,13}\\
p_{31,13} & p_{32,13} & p_{33,13} & p_{34,13}\\
p_{41,13} & p_{42,13} & p_{43,13} & p_{44,13}
\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}p_{11,14} & p_{12,14} & p_{13,14} & p_{14,14}\\
p_{21,14} & p_{22,14} & p_{23,14} & p_{24,14}\\
p_{31,14} & p_{32,14} & p_{33,14} & p_{34,14}\\
p_{41,14} & p_{42,14} & p_{43,14} & p_{44,14}
\end{pmatrix}\\
. & . & . & .\\
. & . & . & .\\
\begin{pmatrix}p_{11,41} & p_{12,41} & p_{13,41} & p_{14,41}\\
p_{21,41} & p_{22,41} & p_{23,41} & p_{24,41}\\
p_{31,41} & p_{32,41} & p_{33,41} & p_{34,41}\\
p_{41,41} & p_{42,41} & p_{43,41} & p_{44,41}
\end{pmatrix} & . & . & \begin{pmatrix}p_{11,44} & p_{12,44} & p_{13,44} & p_{14,44}\\
p_{21,44} & p_{22,44} & p_{23,44} & p_{24,44}\\
p_{31,44} & p_{32,44} & p_{33,44} & p_{34,44}\\
p_{41,44} & p_{42,44} & p_{43,44} & p_{44,44}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}$$

But we can consider the above tensor as a 16 X 16 matrix also. But in that case we will index as:
$$p=\begin{bmatrix}p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13} & . & . & . &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & p_{1,16}\\
p_{21}\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
p_{16,1} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & p_{16,16}
\end{bmatrix}$$
If I define p in Mathematica as:

```
Clear[p]
p[arg__] /; ! OrderedQ@{arg} := Signature@{arg} p @@ Sort@{arg}
p[___, j_, j_, ___] = 0;
Format[p[arg__]] := Subscript[p, arg]
```

and created a 16 X 16 matrix in Mathematica as:

```
pmat = Table[
   If[i > j, RandomReal[], -RandomReal[]], {i, 16}, {j, 16}];
```

How can I map elements from tensor to pmat? For example what is p[1,1,3,4] in pmat?

Comment: Is this `Transpose[Array[Subscript[p, ##] &, {4, 4, 4, 4}], 
  2 <-> 4] // MatrixForm` what you want? BTW, your tensor `p` might be `LeviCivitaTensor[4]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayFlatten[LeviCivitaTensor[4]] // Normal
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$